# What is the fastest way to check if a mysql table is crashed or not?

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql using MyISAM tables. What is the fastest way I can check if a mysql table is crashed or not?

Below are the ways/things I have found which can help me to get result:

- `check table <table_name>`
- `mysqlchk` Program
- `myisamchk` Utility
- `Select * from table_name limit 1`
- `Desc table_name`
- `SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = 'table_name'`

But could not determine which best suits below requirement:

1. it should take least time to check table
2. all other legitimate users should be able to select/insert/update/delete all tables without any issues
3. it should not affect system performance

Currently I am not concerned about how to repair that table but to detect if any table has been crashed

Could anyone please help me in this regard?

Comment: `SHOW TABLE STATUS` should work just fine. So it's quite fast and I can't say for sure if it's "the fastest" - but definitely there should be some point from which the solution may be treated as "applicable". And you should decide where that point is. So - search for "good enough" solutions, not for "good" solutions.

Comment: Switch to InnoDB tables if possible.